# How can i check date values in getview Method

Tags: android

I am working android app,I have display different types of view in My Listview.My problem

is i have displayed 5 items in ListView the Values are status,Required date,Response

date,title,name.How can change Required date values is less than today date listview

background color is red.I can check below model. color is displayed but i can scroll fast

the List View color is not stable.pls help me.......

my getview:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            HashMap<String, String> str=Action_module_screen.mylist.get(position);
           String req=str.get("Req_date");
                          Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar c3 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    c2.set(cyear,cmonth,cday);    
                         Locale l=new Locale(req);
                            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(l);
                            int cyear1 = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int cmonth1 = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int cday1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                             c3.set(cyear1,cmonth1,cday1);         


                  String s=str.get("status");

            if((s.equals("CLO"))||(s.equals("APP"))||(s.equals("ANN"))||(s.equals("ANR"))||(s.equals("AOK")))
            { 
                 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);  
            }
            if(s.equals("NEW"))
            {
                 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  
            }
            if(s.equals("REJ"))
            {
                 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);   
            }   

            if(c2.after(c3))
                  {
                  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                   }


      return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I believe the problem is that you don't have a default background color. Since the views are reused (via the convertView), you might have set the background to RED before, and then when you come back here you might not set the color back to the default, whatever that is supposed to be. Of course, I'm not sure what your data looks like, but there seems to me that there is a possibility that none of your if clauses will match.